# IValidatableObject.Validate does not fire if DataAnnoations add ValidationResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

With a standard ASP.NET MVC controller and view and a model that both implements IValidatableObject and has DataAnnotations, the Validate method never fires if the DataAnnotations generate an exception.

Here's the model...

```
public class ModelStaticDA : IValidatableObject {
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {
        yield return new ValidationResult("MODEL NOT VALID!")
    }  
}
```

Here's the view (client validation is disabled for this demo)...

```
@model BindingAndValidation.Models.ModelStaticDA
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = false;
}
<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>ModelStaticDA</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

If you post something like "invalid" to EmailAddress, only the DataAnnotation message displays.  If you post a valid e-mail address, the message from Validate displays.

Is this the correct behavior?  If so, why?  If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I didn't know that they (data annotation attributes and Validate method) work interchangeably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing everything right, that's the behavior. My guess it was designed this way to avoid having to validate again while working with the properties inside the `Validate` method, you know that when it's called you are working with valid data, and you can do things that require valid data.

Comment: Thanks Max.  What you say makes sense, but I was kind of hoping I had it wrong.